# Python 2.7: String formatting for JSONP

Tags: python, python-2.7, jsonp, newline, string-formatting

I have two scripts that are called separately, `Script 1` calls `Script 2` and the output of both is returned. The result is a JSONP string, which has a newline character caused by `Script 2` adding a new line in the end of `print`.

I'm running `Python 2.7.10`. I usually get one of these errors when executing the second script:

`TypeError: expected a character buffer object` or
`invalid syntax` for using Python 3 commands.

How do I make sure that there is no newline character in the resulting string?

Script 1 (Script 2 call):

```
jsonstring = subprocess.check_output(['python',"scripts/"+path+'.py'],shell=False)
return "%s(%s)" % (request.query.callback, jsonstring)
```

Script 2:

```
import json
def func():
    jsonString = \
        """[ 
            { "DT_RowId": "row_1", "size": "medium", "color": "red" },
            { "DT_RowId": "row_2", "size": "large", "color": "blue" },
            { "DT_RowId": "row_3", "size": "medium", "color": "white" }
        ]"""
    print(jsonString), #end="", flush=True) Available from Python 3
func()
```

Resulting string:

```
jQuery111306445024223066866_1447346051405([{'size': 'medium', 'color': 'red', 'DT_RowId': 'row_1'}, {'size': 'large', 'color': 'blue', 'DT_RowId': 'row_2'}, {'size': 'medium', 'color': 'white', 'DT_RowId': 'row_3'}]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For script 2, please try:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and then use print function without \n in end of line

```
print(jsonString, end='')
```

Related doc: https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3105-print-as-a-function